# how can I interop kotlin code in an existing SBT scala project

Tags: scala, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an existing `scala` project using `SBT` which has several modules.
I'd like to start adding new modules in `kotlin` - I don't require the ability to add `kotlin` to existing modules (but it could be nice if possible)
I can create new dedicated modules for the new `kotlin` code if that is a necessity as long as it is possible for the existing `scala` code to call out to the newly added `kotlin` modules (visa versa is nice to have but can live without that "kotlin calling scala" if impossible to do that)

Is this feasible and practical thing to do? If possible, how would this be done?

```
.
├── build.sbt
............
├── Module1ScalaWithJava (EXISTING)
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── scala
├── Module2ScalaOnly (EXISTING)
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   └── scala
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── scala
├── NewModuleKotlinOnly (I WANT THIS)
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   └── ???KOTLIN????
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin ?

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in comments, you can add kotlin module using [kotlin-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin).

Add line to your `project/plugins.sbt` file (or create it):

`addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "kotlin-plugin" % "2.0.0")`

And you will be able to add `kotlin` modules to your sbt-project. I would advice you using only `build.sbt` file for adding modules. I will demonstrate you how to do that below.

I created simple multi-module project with `scala` and `kotlin` modules which are depends on each other.

Here my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "kotlin-scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val scalaFirst =
  project
    .in(file("scala-first"))

lazy val kotlinFirst =
  project
    .in(file("kotlin-first"))
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % "5.7.0"
      ).map(_ % Test)
    )

lazy val scalaSecond =
  project
    .in(file("scala-second"))
    .dependsOn(kotlinFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.3"
      ).map(_ % Test)
    )

lazy val kotlinSecond =
  project
    .in(file("kotlin-second"))
    .dependsOn(scalaFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % "5.7.0"
      ).map(_ % Test)
    )

lazy val kotlinScalaSubmodule =
  project
    .in(file("kotlin-scala-submodule"))
    .dependsOn(kotlinFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .dependsOn(scalaFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % "5.7.0"
      ).map(_ % Test)
    )

lazy val scalaKotlinSubmodule =
  project
    .in(file("scala-kotlin-submodule"))
    .dependsOn(scalaFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .dependsOn(kotlinFirst % "compile->compile;test->test")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.3"
      ).map(_ % Test)
    )
```

`build.properties` contains:

```
sbt.version = 1.3.2
```

My project structure:

[image: project structure]

Here I have some dependencies between modules:

```
     +---------------+    +--------------+
     |  kotlin-first |    |  scala-first |
     +---------------+    +--------------+
             ^        \  /       ^ 
             |         \/        | 
      +--------------+ || +---------------+
      | scala-second | || | kotlin-second |
      +--------------+ || +---------------+
                       ||
                      /  \
  +------------------+    +------------------+
  | scala-kotlin-sub |    | kotlin-scala-sub |
  +------------------+    +------------------+
```

full project you can find on [github](https://github.com/hardmet/kotlin-scala-example)

Also I write just some unit-tests to demonstrate that it works properly.
Tested on:

- `java` `open-jdk` **1.8**,
- `scala` version **2.13.4**.
- `sbt` version    **1.3.2**
- **Intellij IDEA** build **2020.2.3** with *jetBrains scala plugin* works properly with this project.

Comment: Hello, I pulled your github, but running `sbt test` results in a bunch of errors like: `[error] (scalaKotlinSubmodule / Test / definedTests) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/internal/inc/IncrementalCompile$`, Where you able to run your tests from the command line?

Comment: @MikeRylander It was problem with *sbt version 1.4.3*, I fixed the problem with tests using *sbt 1.3.2* now it works well. You can pull the changes and check it locally.